# removing numbers and characters from column names r

Tags: r, gsub, substitution

I'm trying to remove specific numbers and characters from the column names in a data frame in R but am only able to remove the numbers, have tried different manners but still keep the characters at the end.

Each column is represented as letters and then a number in parenthesis; e.g. ASE (232)

#### DataFrame

```
Subject ASE (232) ASD (121) AFD (313)
   1        1.1.     1.2     1.3
```

#### Desired Data Frame

```
Subject ASE ASD AFD
   1    1.1 1.2 1.3
```

### Code

```
colnames(data)<-gsub("[A-Z] ([0-9]+)","",colnames(data))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may change the code to match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by the opening parentheses (`\\(`, one or more digits (`\\d+`) and other characters (`.*`) and replace with blank (`""`)

```
colnames(data) <- sub("\\s+\\(\\d+.*", "", colnames(data))
colnames(data)
[1] "Subject" "ASE"     "ASD"     "AFD"
```

---

Or another option is `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(colnames(data), whitespace = "\\s+\\(.*")
[1] "Subject" "ASE"     "ASD"     "AFD"
```

---

In the OP's, code, it is matching an upper case letter followed by space and the `(` is a metacharacter, which is not escaped. , thus in regex mode, it captures the digits (`([0-9]+)`).  But, this don't match the pattern in the column names, because after a space, there is a `(`, which is not matched, thus it returns the same string

```
gsub("[A-Z] ([0-9]+)","",colnames(data))
[1] "Subject"   "ASE (232)" "ASD (121)" "AFD (313)"
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Subject = 1L, `ASE (232)` = "1.1.", `ASD (121)` = 1.2, 
    `AFD (313)` = 1.3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: Thanks also for the explanation, didn't think that this sense of regex was enough in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
sub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", colnames(data))
```

This uses backreference `\\1` to "remember" any series of alphanumeric characters `\\w+` and replaces the whole string in `sub`'s replacement argument with just that remembered bit.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `word` from `stringr` package along with `rename_with`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  rename_with(~word(., 1))
```

```
  Subject  ASE ASD AFD
1       1 1.1. 1.2 1.3
```